# Image processing - reusable code

Tags: image

I am going to start working on a image processing project and would like a little information about basic character recognition from an image as simple as reading just a number from an image.
All I am looking for is the logic and some reusable code will be great as well.
Thanks

Comment: SO is not a search engine, you'll get better responses to your question from Google or one of the other fine search engines available.

Answer (score 0):

I used this long back for my side project. Hopefully it is something that you are looking for http://www.aforgenet.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to read a character from an image, you will need to use Optical Character Recognition (OCR). 
There are many question on this subject on stackoverflow and codeproject that you can take a look at like the following:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/870280/ocr-for-net

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/451321/Read-text-from-image-file-in-vb-net.aspx#answer1

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/41709/How-To-Use-Office-2007-OCR-Using-C